I have a scenerio to update a table data
I have a table with colums and data as follows
id    from_date      to_date   value  change_date
10    jan-2021      dec 2021    100    dec-2021
10    jan-2022      dec 2022    100    dec-2022
10    jan-2023      dec 2023    100    dec-2023

I have to update value of 100 to 200 for jan-2023 period at the same time I need to update change_date of jan-2022 and jan-2021 records
from dec 2022 to nov 2022 and dec 2021 to nov 2021 in a single query

A simple option is to use case expression.
As you didn't specify columns' datatypes, I simplifed this example and used strings.
Before:
SQL> select * from test order by from_date;

        ID FROM_DAT TO_DATE       VALUE CHANGE_D
---------- -------- -------- ---------- --------
        10 jan-2021 dec-2021        100 dec-2021
        10 jan-2022 dec-2022        100 dec-2022
        10 jan-2023 dec-2023        100 dec-2023

Update:
SQL> update test set
  2    value = case when from_date = 'jan-2023' then 200 else value end,
  3    change_date = case when from_date = 'jan-2021' then 'nov-2021'
  4                       when from_date = 'jan-2022' then 'nov-2022'
  5                       else change_date
  6                  end;

3 rows updated.

After:
SQL> select * from test order by from_date;

        ID FROM_DAT TO_DATE       VALUE CHANGE_D
---------- -------- -------- ---------- --------
        10 jan-2021 dec-2021        100 nov-2021
        10 jan-2022 dec-2022        100 nov-2022
        10 jan-2023 dec-2023        200 dec-2023

SQL>


I have one more issue..  I have a table level trigger for each row value and id.  The way it has to work.. if I update value then change date  and to_date has to update and it is working fine. If I update change date then to_date should not update and this is working fine as well. But in case if I update value of one row and change date of other row with these case statement then for two records To_date is being updated

here the only that that should be updated is for the row value field is updated.. Not sure why trigger is firing when i update change_dat along with field value

I wouldn't know. From the Stack Overflow perspective, that's a different problem and you should open a new question for it. Please, post some sample data and trigger code because - it is difficult to debug code you can't see.

update test set
2    value = case when from_date = 'jan-2023' then 200 else value end,
3    change_date = case when from_date = 'jan-2021' then 'nov-2021'
4                   --    when from_date = 'jan-2022' then 'nov-2022'
5                       else change_date
6                  end and  from_date between jan-2020 and jan-2024  and id =10.. The  above code should update only two records as  I commented case for jan-2022 but I see three records updated after compiling above code

I presume that's because you're comparing strings. "jan-2021" is a string, which means that e.g. "jan" (January) comes AFTER "dec" (December) of the same year. What to do? Don't store dates as strings - use DATE datatype column (and then apply TO_CHAR function to display it in any format you want). Or, if you can't modify data model, apply TO_DATE with appropriate format mask, e.g. where to_date(from_date, 'mon-yyyy') between date '2020-01-01' and date '2020-12-31' (or any of its variations).

just for the post I have added it as jan-2021 but actually I'm using correct date format as you mentioned

UPDATE test
SET
value = CASE  WHEN from_date = 'jan-2023' THEN 200
ELSE value
END
``WHERE from_dat BETWEEN jan - 2020 AND jan - 2024
AND id = 10;

this is also updating three records

If everything is OK with column datatype, then: according to sample data you posted, there really are 3 rows whose FROM_DATE is between January 2020 and January 2024.
